# how to change install postgis location? postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

When I am in my postgres db and tried to create an extension for my db, I get this error

`ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory`

I know there are so many posts out there with this error and solutions and I tried them all too.  Found so much in stackoverflow but none of them worked.

I realized in my `postgresql` directory there are `9.2`, `9.3`, `9.4`, `9.5`, `9.6`,

I went into the directory in the error and I realized there is really no `postgis.control` inside `9.5`

I checked my psql version and showed 9.6.1

I went into `9.6` folder and I DO see a `postgis.control` in it.

I want to changed the installation directory so when i run

`create extension postgis`

it would go

`"/usr/share/postgresql/9.6/extension/postgis.control"`

instead of

`"/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/postgis.control"`

Can someone please give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Using Ubuntu 14.04 and also have Ubuntu 16.04 as desktop which I haven't try to install postgis yet

Comment: The PostGIS package is specific to a Postgres version. You just need to install one for 9.5 (e.g. [`postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3`](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/postgresql/trusty-pgdg/main/base/postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3)).

Answer (score 34):

You should use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6-postgis-scripts
```

Comment: on a recent ubuntu, even `sudo apt install postgis` does work - it installs all the needed libraries, that work with the installed postgres version.

Comment: `sudo apt install postgis` - beware of such kind of installation if you don't have postgres of latest version - because that command install also latest postgres and make it default for your system.

Answer (score -2):

Use the following command to get the [postgis.control](/questions/tagged/postgis.control) in your 9.5 version directory:

sudo apt install postgis postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3