# How to install Postgis to a Keg installation of Postgres@9.5 using Homebrew?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, postgis, postgresql-9.5

I have installed Postgresql@9.5 to my OSX El Capitan Machine using Homebrew 1.2. Unfortunately, upon installing Postgis, and performing CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

It returns,

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.5/9.5.6/share/postgresql@9.5/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

I tried, uninstalling all postgresql and install only the 9.5 version, and then installing postgis but to no avail.

I think I got a similar question but this one is only for Ubuntu.
[how to change install postgis location? postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666196/how-to-change-install-postgis-location-postgres)

[This discussion also instruct to install postgresql using @ notation but didn't tell that it will create a non-comformant directory name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Comment: See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079305/how-to-install-postgis-to-a-keg-installation-of-postgres9-6-using-homebrew/48096389#48096389) for [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079305/how-to-install-postgis-to-a-keg-installation-of-postgres9-6-using-homebrew/).