# How to install Postgis to a Keg installation of Postgres@9.6 using Homebrew?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, postgis, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.6

I have installed Postgresql@9.6 and Postgis via Homebrew. However, installing Postgis via Homebrew installs the latest version of Postgresql at 10 as dependency and pinning Postgresql at 9.6.5 blocks the install of Postgis via Homebrew.

Performing 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis;' returns:

`ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.5/share/postgresql@9.6/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory`

I've also tried uninstalling the Postgresql (at 10) and editing the Postgis formula to depend on Postgres@9.6 instead of Postgresql.

This is similar to [How to install Postgis to a Keg installation of Postgres@9.5 using Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845177/how-to-install-postgis-to-a-keg-installation-of-postgres9-5-using-homebrew) but with a later keg formula

Comment: "asked 6 hours ago" -- I literally laughed out loud at seeing this.  I'm having the exact same problem, researching it actively. (yes, I know this isn't a helpful comment...)

Comment: Another poor soul having the [same question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/261525/23119). Only saw yours after posting mine, sorry. Another possible approach might be described [here](https://gist.github.com/gopperman/18cb66078372d3261420829630230b80#comments) but I am still hesitating to try.

Answer (score 10):

I managed to do it after many combinations.
In a nutshell, solution is to install the old version of the original package `postgres`, switch to it, and install the old version of `postgis`.

#### Install postgres

1/ Install the current version of `postgres` (10.1 as speaking)

```
brew install postgres
```

2/ Install the old version of postgres using its old formula. Proper link can be found using [github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/postgresql.rb) or `git log` on the Tap repo (`/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/`).

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/d014fa223f77bee4b4097c5e80faa0954e28182f/Formula/postgresql.rb
```

This will install the version 9.6.5 (last one before 10.x series).

3/ Switch to it so links are defaulted to postgres 9.6

```
brew switch postgres 9.6.5
```

#### Install postgis

4/ Install old version of postgis (2.3). This is using the same sha version of the Formula so everything is linked correctly (using the current postgis will expect postgresql 10, so it will end up to a version mismatch when initializing extension).

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/d014fa223f77bee4b4097c5e80faa0954e28182f/Formula/postgis.rb
```

#### Use them

5/ If required initialise the DB

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

6/ Create and use your DB

```
createdb mydb
psql mydb
mydb=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Comment: I had to `brew unlink postgres` between steps 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks @Antwan, massive help here. I think there is a 9.6.8 in homebrew somehow/somewhere, but I *think* that is related to the `postgresql@9.6` based installation which (as others have found too) won't work with `brew switch postgresql 9.6.8`. Just leaving this comment here for my future self, once I come back to it.

Comment: Looks like installation of 10.1 also initializes a database in a new format. So I had to remove `/usr/local/var/postgres` and make initdb after switching to 9.6 in order to make it work (Do it on your own risk. You will lose ALL the data if you have something there)

Comment: This seemed like a really good solution, and I was really hopeful it was going to work. Unfortunately for me, step (2) fails with `Error: postgresql: Unsupported special dependency :python`

Answer (score 7):

Installing [PEX](https://github.com/petere/pex), a package manager for Postgresql allowed me to install Postgis for the keg version of Postgresql@9.6 and use `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

This isn't a Homebrew solution but after a lot of searching, it finally allowed me to use Postgis.

Comment: Worked brilliantly.  One caveat for future searchers: don't bother trying the `brew` install of `pex`, it has the same issue that it will install PostgreSQL 10 for you (at least for now).

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: It took a lot of mucking about, but eventually I got this to work. In case anyone else runs into the same problems, here are the problems I encountered and the solutions I found to them: https://gist.github.com/skissane/0487c097872a7f6d0dcc9bcd120c2ccd

Answer (score 1):

Hello

I ran into this same problem of multiple implementation of pgsql versions including legacy ones. So after a bit of research I would like to share my solution.

**Problem:**

I am working on a macbook pro 2013 with 10.11 el capitan. I am GIS developer and extensive user of homebrew. I didn't pin the postgresql package for compatibility reasons. Thus, the package got updated to postgresql version 10.5 along other packages. This caused me to be unable to use postgresql version 9.4. The cleverest solution would have been to use a `brew switch postgresql 9.4.19`. Except that when compiling postgis 2.5.0 from `osgeo/osgeo4mac` it defautls (looks for) the postgresql binary folder to install the symlinked (or not) extensions. Here again another compatibility problem. One could tinker a bit with homebrew files and transfer files manually. That's ill advice...the package manager (homebrew) needs to stay a coherent ecosystem to provide for a stable workspace.

**Proposed Solution:**

1. Go here [BigSQL](https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/postgresql/installers/) and download the dmg of your chosen version
2. install the software where you want in your filesystem
3. within the installation folder you'll find a directory named `pg9x` ; x being the version number (e.g pg95 for postgresql 9.5 and so on...
4. in this folder you'll find a file named `pg9x.env`
5. source this file to your `.profile` with `source /your/path/pg9x/pg9x.env` line
6. in the main installation folder, for instance `/your/path/pg9x/`, you'll finde a python script called `pgc`, alias it to your `.profile` with `alias pgc="your/path/pgc"`
7. save your `.profile` and refresh your environment variable with `source .profile` on the command prompt
8. still within the command prompt, type `pgc list`, you'll get a list of installed packages. You'll see the version of postgesql you've downloaded
9. to install another version of postgresql, say 9.6, type `pgc install pg96`
10. to install postgis for pg95 type `pgc install postgis22-pg95`
11. to install postgis for pg96 type `pgc install postgis23-pg96`
12. now, after installation you'll need to initialize the downloaded component with `pgc init pg96` or `pgc init postgis23-pg96` etc...
13. to check if your daemon is running correctly type `pgc status`
14. to start a version daemon of your choice type for example `pgc start pg95`
15. to stop a version daemon of your choice type `pgc stop pg95`
16. the installation also comes with an LTS release of pgadmin3 that works fine with all versions (not the case of brew version of pgadmin3), this is very convenient
17. type `pgc help` for more options

Let the elephant dance^^

Hope this helps.

Spicy.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and what worked for me was to follow the instructions at https://github.com/CloverHealth/homebrew-tap, which seem similar in spirit to @Antwan's solution but with a few more clean up steps, also it gets slightly later versions: postgresql 9.6.10 and postgis 2.5.

My steps differed slightly from those at CloverHealth: My brew version no longer supports `brew switch postgresql 9.6.10` and I tried first `brew link postgresql@9.6.10` and then `brew link postgresql@9.6` but both gave

```
Error: no such keg
```

Trying `brew search postgresql` showed a little green checkmark next to the cloverhealth Formulae, so I tried `brew link cloverhealth/tap/postgresql` and got

```
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.10
```

So, ok it was already linked.  Other than that my steps were the same as described at the CloverHealth page, and now I'm up and running again.